# What is use of direct_document_copy in data migration config.xml

Tags: magento2, configuration, data-migration

I have recently migrate M1 DB to M2 DB there is option in `config.xml` called `direct_document_copy`

```
 <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
```

There is comment that set it to 1 for better performance.But the question is why isn't set default 1. Is there any special requirement to enable this?

> 2) Mysql server has gone away

in the same file `<bulk_size>0</bulk_size>` this was set to 0 and a was getting `Mysql server has gone away` in migration process.

But when i changed it to `<bulk_size>500</bulk_size>` it was completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

```
<direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
```

No any specific reason to set 1 its already worked when set 0 by default is 0

when you set 1 so its perform better

```
<direct_document_copy>1</direct_document_copy>
```

Set 1 it will direct copy data from database, like 'source' and 'destination' databases should be same placed. Database account must have access to each database.

`bulk_size=0` it will be auto-detected for every files document

also you can follow this : [docs link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-overview-practices.html)